# Закрыть активити свайпом вниз

Tags: android, activity, android-animation, swipe

Нашел недавно такой пример:

[image: пример]

и захотелось реализовать нечто похожее. Меня интересует реализация момента, когда пользователь в открывшейся карточке прокрутил список до верха, развернул картинку и **продолжает вести палец вниз, при этом вся карточка тоже начинает съезжать** (соответственно потом пользователь отпускает палец, и активити закрывается с определенной анимацией). Есть ли библиотеки для реализации такого?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все методы, которые реализуют то, что вы хотите, основаны на обработке  `MotionEvent.Event` (с опредленными вычислениями внутри) и установкой к стилю свойства `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>`. Если не хочется самому разбираться, можно использовать следующие библиотеки:

- [Slidr](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1364)
- [SwipeBackLayout](https://github.com/ikew0ng/SwipeBackLayout)